# Javascript add bold text to a frame

Tags: javascript

I want to add bold to the (see illustration). If I do this:

```
        p:function{
        sel = this.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        var caretPosition = sel.endOffset;
        var existingText = this.iframe[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerText;

        var before = existingText.substring(0, caretPosition);
        var after = existingText.substring(caretPosition);

        this.iframe[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML= before 
        +'**<b>**(see illustration)**</b>** ' + after;
        },
```

Then all the text that i write after (see illustration becomes bold).

[image]
[image]

Comment: [`execCommand()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.execCommand) might be helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create an editable `iframe` with Bold, Italic or other commands you can use the underlying browser commands which you can fire through the `execCommand` method.

You could see there resources for more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.execCommand
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla

These method is supported by all modern browsers.

Comment: Thank you, I found a way to use execCommand, but only when the user selects the text. And I want a way to preinsert a bold value

Comment: @alex1111 Do you want to add some bold text into `iframe` ?

Answer (score 1):

I've provided a simple example that shows you how `execCommand` works

```
<iframe id = "my-editable">
    <html>
        <body contenteditable = "true">
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

JavaScript code:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('my-editable');
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

// type and select some text into iframe
// For making selected text to be bold, just execute the following command
iframeDoc.execCommand('bold');
```

**UPDATE**

```
var body = iframeDoc.body;
body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML + '<b>' + 'your bold text' + '</b>' + 'your boldless text'
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont want to make the selected text into bold, I want to insert a boldless text + bold text + boldless text :)

Comment: @alex1111 It's pretty easy, just see my edit for awhile later

Comment: I tried this but there is a problem: when I add more text to the end of bold text this added text is bold too, and I dont want that..

Comment: I realized what the problem was: when the variable after was empty-> '' then I would face this problem. So now I add a &nbsp and it's ok :) Thank you